# the bullet does not move in a straight line

Tags: game-development, qt6

The idea of the whole code is that, creating a tower which is a polygon and then detect any item that is entered to that polygon item.

When an enemy entered to the tower the code creates a line between the center of tower and the center of enemy, at this moment everything is fine. Now after creating this line I calculated the angle between this line and the x axis, after that I give this angle to createbullet() function for create a bullet with this angle (the bullet when it created at the first time it is vertical so for make it with the same angle of that line. I did `-(lineangle-90)`, I did negative sign because setrotation  count in clockwise ),also at this moment  everything is good.

The problem comes when the bullet moves. In the move function with my calculation I tried to make the bullet moves along this line, with our previous code the bullet already on the line so what we need now is just calculate the position of the heat of the bullet and then make it in that position after some seconds. So I did the code which is in the move function, but as I said here is the problem, my bullet does not go align this code, and as I think the only possible problem is with the angle that I use in this move function. Anyway the behaviour of my bullet is [image]
and

[image]

you can see that the bullet after some times will not lie on the line but it seem like it will parallel with it.

[image]

the last picture is very clear, look at bullet where is after it's movement.

bullet.cpp:

```
int im_width;
int im_height;

bullet::bullet()
{

    setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
  setPos(350-this->boundingRect().width()/2,350-this->boundingRect().height()/2);

    QTimer *timer=new QTimer(this);

    connect(timer,&QTimer::timeout,this,&bullet::move);
    timer->start(20);

}

void bullet::move()
{
   **int theta=180-rotation();**
   **// int theta=rotation()-90;**
    double dx=qCos( qDegreesToRadians(theta))*3;
    double dy=qSin(qDegreesToRadians(theta))*3;

    setPos( x()+dx, y()+dy);

}
```

tower.cpp:

```
tower::tower()
{
    QTimer *tm2=new QTimer(this);
    connect(tm2,&QTimer::timeout,this,&tower::checkforenemy);
    tm2->start(2000);


}

void tower::createbullet(int lineangle)
{
    bull=new bullet();


    bull->setRotation(-lineangle+90);
   // bull->setTransformOriginPoint(bull->boundingRect().center());

    gm->sc->addItem(bull);

}

void tower::checkforenemy()
{
    QList<QGraphicsItem*> attackers=del->collidingItems();
    QList<QPointF> attackers_center;
    QPointF point(150,150);
    QPointF tower_center=QPointF(mapToScene(point));
    QList<QLineF> lines;
    int lineangle[10];
    point=QPointF(mapToScene(point));
    int c=0;
    enemy *e[10];
    QGraphicsLineItem *LinesItem[10];
    for(int i=0;i<attackers.size();i++){
        if(typeid(*(attackers[i]))==typeid(enemy)){
             e[c] = dynamic_cast<enemy*>(attackers[i]);
            attackers_center.push_back(e[c]->boundingRect().center());
             lines.push_back(QLineF(tower_center,attackers_center[c]));
            LinesItem[c]=new QGraphicsLineItem(lines[c]);
             gm->sc->addItem(LinesItem[c]); 
             tower::createbullet(lines[c].angle());

           // qDebug()<<e->boundingRect().center();
            c++;

        }
    }
}
```